# How network errors are handled in Axios vs Fetch?

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch-api

I've just finished reading an Article about **Fetch vs Axios** [here](https://medium.com/frontend-digest/axios-vs-fetch-which-to-use-in-2019-6678c083c5c):

The author makes a point about:

> “*Axios throws network errors, while fetch does not. When working with fetch, you must always check the response.ok property*”

and Axios doesn’t need `if (!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText)`

I don't quite understand why and how network errors are handled in Axios and is it correct that Axios request doesn't require the `if(!response.statusText !== 'OK') throw new Error(....)` ?

Also here is my axios request please would you say its good standard at the least?

```
 const fetchData = async (url) => {
        setFetchError(false);
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('/api/movies');
            return response.data;
        } catch (err) {
            setFetchError(true);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't quite understand why and how network errors are handled in
>   Axios & is it correct that Axios request doesn't require the
>   if(!response.statusText !== 'OK') throw new Error(....) ?

It is correct that Axios doesn't require to check if status of response isn't OK(2XX status code).

IMHO Axios leverage the concept of network status code to throw errors, such as responses with 4XX and 5XX status. (You can check more HTTP status response [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)) You will see that MDN separate HTTP status code in 4 categories: information, success, redirect and error.

As a programmer I prefer to use Axios than Fetch just because how it handles network errors.